# How to retrieve TBs of data from HDFS using Rhdfs package?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, rhadoop

How to retrieve TBs of data from HDFS using Rhdfs package because data is stored on multiple machines and R runs on single machine.

How this much much amount of data is stored in R dataframe on a single system. If so, how can that huge data is stored in single hardware, basically which conflicts Big Data Storage concept.

Comment: Have you seen SparkR - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html

Comment: Yeah. I had worked on SparkR. I want to know. How R retrives this much data on Its intrrface. Because I didn't use distributed environment while running R job with Spark and Hadoop.